# How to configure Javascript to output 'NaN' + number = number (i.e) 'NaN+32=32 and not 'NaN'

Tags: javascript

is there any way to configure Javascript to output 'NaN' + number = number  (i.e) 'NaN'+32=32

Comment: why not make `NaN` to 0 and achieve it?

Comment: This seems very much like a typical [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem; what problem are you trying to solve that led to this question?

Comment: If you want the code to behave differently normally it takes rewriting the code itself, not configuring the interpreter. If Javascript starts to handle NaN differently then other js code might not work anymore.

Comment: If your code is rendering NaN, I would solve the issue at it's origin rather than modify it in calculation. I assume you are expecting an int.